# SIGKILL signal everytime I stop debugging

Tags: ios, sigkill

I have Xcode 4.2 and whenever I run my app in the simulator and I press the stop debugging button, I get a sigkill message. The breakpoint stops in the main.m file at this line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I know that when I force quit the app (from xcode's stop button) it would make sense to receive this, but I dont receive this when I do the same thing on my other apps. Sometimes I get a random sigkill message when I run the app (probably memory related, but I haven't found it yet)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thats's somehow expected because a SIGKILL signal is really sent everyime you stop or relaunch the debugger.

You can try the band-aid solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682277/xcode-4-2-jumps-to-main-m-every-time-after-stopping-simulator). In short:

1. Open preferences and then Behaviors;
2. Select "Run completes";
3. Mark "Show tab" and fill the input with "Edit"
4. Do the same with "Run exits unexpectedly"

About the random sigkills, maybe you should track references counting with Instruments. There's a section about it on the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/ViewingandAnalyzingData/ViewingandAnalyzingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH5) if you will.